# SQL Server Trigger Error-Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql-server, triggers

Ok so I'm really stuck, my trigger is causing this error: Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Sofi_TERA_Trigger, Line 15
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

At the begining I thought it was my "if" but I changed it (use "IN" at the place of multiple "AND" conditions). I've also looked for my error, but it can be related to pretty much anything.

It's probably something quite simple that I can't see. Here's my trigger:

```
TRIGGER [dbo].[Sofi_TERA_Trigger]
   ON [dbo].ZZ
   AFTER UPDATE,INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF ((Select inserted.Statut from inserted) IN ('*CLOT*','*CLTT*','*CONF*'))
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @Id int;
            DECLARE @Matricule varchar(10);
            DECLARE @IdAction int;
            DECLARE @NumeroOF int; 
            SELECT @NumeroOF = inserted.Ordre from inserted;

            DECLARE OF_CURSOR CURSOR
                LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY
            FOR
            SELECT Id,Log.Matricule,IdAction from Log inner join (select max(Id) as maxID,Matricule from LOG where Log.NumeroOF = @NumeroOF group by Matricule) maxID 
            on maxID.maxID = Log.Id where Log.NumeroOF = @NumeroOF;

            OPEN OF_CURSOR
            FETCH NEXT FROM OF_CURSOR INTO @Id,@Matricule,@IdAction
            WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
            BEGIN
                IF @IdAction!=13
                    BEGIN
                        IF @IdAction<=2
                        BEGIN
                            insert into Log(NumeroOF,Matricule,IdAction,Date,EstAdmin) values (@NumeroOF,@Matricule,13,GETDATE(),1);
                        END
                        ELSE
                        BEGIN
                            insert into Log(NumeroOF,Matricule,IdAction,Date,EstAdmin) values (@NumeroOF,@Matricule,2,GETDATE(),1);
                            insert into Log(NumeroOF,Matricule,IdAction,Date,EstAdmin) values (@NumeroOF,@Matricule,13,GETDATE(),1);
                        END
                    END              
                FETCH NEXT FROM OF_CURSOR INTO @Id,@Matricule,@IdAction
            END

            CLOSE OF_CURSOR;
            DEALLOCATE OF_CURSOR;
    END 
END
```

Comment: You need to change `IF ((Select inserted.Statut from inserted) IN ('*CLOT*','*CLTT*','*CONF*'))` for `IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM inserted WHERE inserted.Statut IN ('*CLOT*','*CLTT*','*CONF*'))`

Comment: Exactly what I needed, you can make an answer if you want and I'll accept it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the line:

```
IF((Select inserted.Statut from inserted) IN ('*CLOT*','*CLTT*','*CONF*'))
```

Is not valid syntax. You need to change it for:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM inserted WHERE inserted.Statut IN ('*CLOT*','*CLTT*','*CONF*'))
```